# namedValues working in Sheet script but not a Form script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, typeerror, undefined, google-forms

I've created a simple form with one question "Name", sending out an automated email after submissions and was trying to use namedValues to reference the info. However if I create the script thru the sheet itself it works but if I create the script via the form I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined at onFormSubmit(Code:18:27)

Here's the code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const formResponse = e.namedValues;
  const emailRecipients = 'someemail@gmail.com';
  const emailSubject = 'Subject of email'; 
  let name = formResponse.Name.toString().trim();
  let htmlBody = `<p>${name}</p>`;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailRecipients, emailSubject, '', { htmlBody: htmlBody });
}
```

I've created triggers, etc, but the only real difference is where I'm placing the code.  Previously used the 'getItemResponses' method in the form script with no problems however was just trying to figure out how to use, if possible, 'namedValues' via the form script instead a sheet script since the final form will have about 30 different questions.

Here's the example of the line I was using with no issues whatsoever:

```
const email = responses.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse().trim();
```

Comment: Form Script has an entirely different event object

Comment: Would you know what that event object would be?

Comment: [Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer that we can't use namedValues thru a form but must be in a sheet since that's where the values are stored.

Comment: The event objects have different properties on each app. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events